# How do I find common files changed between git branches?

Tags: git

I have an upstream repository with some changes.  I have local changes I want to rebase onto the upstream changes.  I want to know what files I've changed locally have also changed upstream so I can check any automatic merging.  Alternatively, I'd like to manually do any merges during the rebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanded a bit: for you first part of the question, make a new branch, automatically do the rebase there, and then compare to your working copy.

```
git branch workBranch
git commit #throw your locals into your own branch for a brief moment
git branch testBranch
git rebase otherBranch
git diff workBranch
```

You might also get away with just doing a "git diff origin/branchToMerge"

For the interactive part:

```
git rebase --interactive.
```

Set all the commits to "Edit" and you'll be taken through each of them one-by-one giving you a chance to see everything done for that commit and edit to your heart's content.

**EDIT to answer comment**

OK, for strictly seeing changed files, do:

```
git log a0a0a0..b1b1b1 --name-only --pretty=oneline | egrep -v '^[a-f0-9]{40} ' | sort | uniq > lista
git log a0a0a0..c2c2c2 --name-only --pretty=oneline | egrep -v '^[a-f0-9]{40} ' | sort | uniq > listb
cat lista listb | sort | uniq -d
```

That bit of shell kludgery will show you only files that changed in both logs. For a0a0a0, use your common point. Replace the b1/c2 strings with the tips of the two diverging branches.

Comment: If I compare my rebased branch to my work branch, won't it show all the changes in otherBranch, not just the set of files changed in *both* workBranch and otherBranch.

Comment: I ended up doing a merge in a test branch and then looking at all of the "automatically merged" messages.  Thanks for the script though, I may use that next time.

Comment: instead of egrep try --pretty="format:" with --name-only that will remove all the other stuff and just leave some blank lines

Answer (score 12):

### Listing changed files

Since a rebase/merge can be time-consuming, it's best to avoid doing an unnecessary one. There are a variety of ways to see what's been changed, depending on what sort of information you need.

If you're interested in knowing per commit what files have changed, I'd suggest `git-log`:

```
git log [--pretty=<format>] --name-only <common-branch>..<local-branch>
```

You can use the `--pretty` option to get the header information you need; `<format>` can be a variety of choices, including a custom string with fields - see the man page for more information.

The `--name-only` option is actually being passed through to `git-diff`, so if you don't care about per-commit results, you can go straight to the source:

```
git diff --name-only <common-branch> <local-branch>
```

Note that the branches are specified differently for the two commands.

You can apply this to the upstream changes as well, changing `<local-branch>` to `<upstream-branch>`, and end up with two lists of files. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how you want to compare them, though the -f option of grep can be handy...

### Manual merges

Autocracy beat me to this. If you've done some smart processing based on output of `git-log` you could edit only the commits you saw had overlapping file changes. If you were merging rather than rebasing, you'd use the `--no-commit` option.

See also the configuration section of the `git-merge` man page. You might want to set merge.conflictstyle to diff3, so that you can see the original text as well as the changes on either side.

If you're really desperate to suppress all attempts at automatic conflict resolution, I believe you could plug in a dummy mergetool (via merge.tool and mergetool.cmd) that does nothing and returns failure.

Having said all of this, I should also say that in my experience with git merges, I have seen plenty of conflicts but cannot remember a single incorrect automatic merge. I personally trust it's merging capabilities. Checking up on it after should really be plenty.

Comment: I trust git's merge, but sometimes it would be nice to know what things you need to concentrate your testing on if you've changed a bunch of files.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old topic, but we found that git diff --name-only was returning too many false positive modified files if the two branches are too differents.
Here's what we use at work to perform review code for commits of a new branch against our feature branch (possibly already partially merged in the feature branch).

being in our new_branch and under *nix system we use this command:

```
git show --name-only $( git cherry -v feature_branch | grep '^+' | awk '{ print($2) }' ) | egrep -v '^(commit |Author:|Date:|\s|$)' | sort -u
```

replacing feature_branch by the name of the branch you want to check modified files against.

The advantages of this techniques is that it really sorts only files modified by commits that belong to your branch and that are not already merged in your feature_branch.

If you want to check between two commits SHA1 and SHA2 you also can do:

```
git show --name-only $( git cherry -v SHA1 SHA2 | grep '^+' | awk '{ print($2) }' ) | egrep -v '^(commit |Author:|Date:|\s|$)' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

this will list the top 20 files of your branch which has changed most frequently

git log --pretty=format: --name-only | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg | head -20