# How do I export modified/added files between revisions with Netbeans/Github?

Tags: netbeans, github, export

I'm using Github for Windows together with NetBeans IDE. How do I export files from one revision to another in git? I can see the revisions and what files are there and there is an option to export a specific revision, but I want to export modifications between two revisions.

I basically want files that is modified/changed from revision 2 to revision 5 revision exported to a temporary folder. **Is this possible?** I could of course export each commit but that's seems so wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply:

- [list all modified files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16220005/6309) (based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6827937/6309))

  ```
  git diff --name-status [SHA1 [SHA2]]
  ```
- copy all the modified files from that list to a temporary folder.